# Proxy TCP and UDP traffic to multiple servers in backend at the same time

Tags: nginx

I am tring to forward traffic of tcp and udp into multiple servers at the same time. What i found is only load balance it in Nginx.
Does there a feature in Nginx can handle this type of forwarding/proxing?

Comment: Not a programming question and thus off-topic here. Check out e.g. superuser.com, but this time first read the site guidelines.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the workings of TCP.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not TCP/UDP but for HTTP there is NGINX [mirror module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html):

> The `ngx_http_mirror_module module` (1.13.4) implements mirroring of an original request by creating background mirror subrequests. Responses to mirror subrequests are ignored.

Example Configuration

```
location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}

location = /mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://test_backend$request_uri;
}
```